# Convert values in one column based on string condition in another column?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
structure(list(Variable = c("Temperature Farenheit", "Temperature Farenheit", 
"Temperature Celcius "), Value = c(67L, 77L, 32L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I would like to standardize the units, so that all the values are represented in Celsius.
If `Variable` includes the word "Farenheit", I would like to convert the corresponding value to Celsius. No need to change the values that already represent Celsius.

For example, the first row represents a fahrenheit temperature (67 F), so I would like to convert it to C:

(67°F − 32) × 5/9 = 19.4444

Answer (score 2):

given your dataframe is called df:

```
df[grep("Farenheit", df$Variable), "Value"] <- 
   (df[grep("Farenheit", df$Variable), "Value"] - 32) * 5 / 9
```

does the work

Comment: `df$Value <- ifelse(grepl("Farenheit", df$Variable), (df$Value - 32) * 5 / 9, df$Value)` another way

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function/dplyr option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- structure(list(Variable = c("Temperature Farenheit", "Temperature Farenheit", 
                            "Temperature Celcius "), Value = c(67L, 77L, 32L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    -3L))

conversion <- function(data) {
  data %>% 
    mutate(Value = ifelse(str_detect(Variable, "Farenheit"), (Value - 32) * 5/9, Value),
           Variable = "Temperature Celcius")
}


conversion(df)
#>              Variable    Value
#> 1 Temperature Celcius 19.44444
#> 2 Temperature Celcius 25.00000
#> 3 Temperature Celcius 32.00000
```